# HTML (5) Column Troubles with Positioning

Tags: css, html

This should be a pretty trivial issue, but it's causing me a bit of a headache.

I have an html layout, summarized with the relevant code below. Basically I have the `<section>` and `<aside>` acting as the main content, and the right handed content. I am trying to make sure they will always behave in this manner, regardless of any kind of funky boundaries caused by borders, margins, padding, etc. The solution seemed to be simply setting them to have absolute and relative positioning.

This did achieve my desired result, but I am having trouble with the underlying content. The `<article>` does not stretch to the right height. Since the height is not always determinable at code-time, giving it a set height is not an option. My intended goal is that the underlying `<article>` background will stretch to accommodate no matter how high either of the `<section>` or `<aside>` panes become. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .container { margin: 0px auto; width: 960px; position: relative }

        article { 
            overflow: hidden;  
            background-color: Black;  
            height: auto; 
        }

        section { 
            width: 675px; 
            position: relative; 
            left: 0px; 
            overflow: hidden; 
            margin: 10px; 
            height: 300px; 
            background-color: Aqua; 
        }
        aside {  
            width: 260px;  
            position: absolute; 
            right: 0px; 
            top: 0px; 
            overflow: hidden; 
            margin: 10px; 
            height: 500px; 
            background-color: Fuchsia; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <article>
            <section>
            </section>
            <aside>
            </aside>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as is see it, article is an inline element, so it will take as much space as it needs. you could change it to a block element, but im not sure if it will break something else

Comment: I've tried adding `display: block;` to it and it doesn't fix the issue. The article still refuses to stretch.

Comment: Try setting `<article>` to `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. No dice, unfortunately.

Comment: which browser do you use? in my firefox there is a difference (see:http://jsfiddle.net/9R7Mx/)

Comment: My suggestion for equal height columns is faux columns.  http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/   I'm not sure why you decided to use absolute positioning for this.

Comment: The faux columns thing is neat, but it only works if the content is larger than the sidebar - and this will not always be the case in my situation.

Comment: @Fender: I just tried your jsfiddle in FireFox and I get the same results I get in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: faux columns works no matter which column is bigger.  http://imaginekitty.com/cssExamples/fauxForStacey.html

Comment: @Stacey i discovered in opera, that it will only strech the column if there is some content. try adding a letter to section and aside and it should work (i does in opera and firefox 3.6)

Comment: @mark123: Yes, this was actually how I was doing things before - the problem was that margins and padding and such kept screwing it up, so I wanted to use absolute positioning to make sure that wouldn't happen.

Comment: I don't think absolute positioning is the panacea you think it is.  It's not so great for placing major layout elements.  In your case, I believe it is unnecessary at best.

Comment: @mark123: can you post your information as an actual answer so I can award credit?

Comment: I will post my code from the example if you'd like.

Comment: @Fender, [article](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-article-element) is a block-level element, as it may contain [flow content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#flow-content). You do have to specify `display` on html5 elements to get them to work in most browsers ATM.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I figured this was the case. No matter how many years you spend in HTML, it's still always a challenge to make site layouts work right. Always trying to find the perfect balance of markup, styles, and simplicity.

Comment: @Stacey, browsers are supposed to treat unrecognized elements as not being there, so all browsers (used to) ignore the HTML5 tags. The more advanced ones would recognize new elements once you specified a display style for them, but the elephant in the room is still IE in that it's not dynamic enough to recognize and style new elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here is the code with faux columns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Faux column example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .container {
            margin-bottom: 2em;
        }
            article { 
                background: #000 url(http://imaginekitty.com/cssExamples/oog.gif) repeat-y; 
                    border: solid 10px #000; 
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
                min-height: 100%; 
            width: 945px;
                    overflow: hidden;  
            }
                section { 
                    display: block;
                    float: left;
                    overflow: hidden; 
                    width: 668px; 
            }
            aside {  
                    float: left;
                    margin-left: 20px; 
                    overflow: hidden; 
                    width: 255px;  
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <p>There is no use of absolute or relative positioning here.</p>
        <article>
            <section>
        <p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p>
            </section>
            <aside><p>asdf</p>
            </aside>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <article>
            <section>
        <p>asdf</p>
            </section>
            <aside><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p><p>asdf</p>
            </aside>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason I mentioned that absolute positioning is, in my opinion, inappropriate in this situation is that it removes elements from the normal document flow which will most likely cause issues with other elements on the page.  At best, it's just unnecessary.  At worst, you'll pull your hair out trying to figure out problems.  :)

A good article on the subject: http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/absolute-positioning-pitfalls/

Comment: +1 Yep, it´s the absolute positioning that´s causing the problem.

Comment: I am trying to take the approach that requires the least amount of markup and css while achieving the same result. I have learned that, while I can style everything separately, it becomes monolithic if I do. I felt that absolute positioning might reduce a lot of the roundabout ways I have to go about certain kinds of layout by adding 'filler' `<div>` and `<span>` tags to make certain formatting work.

Comment: Obviously, if it just adds more problems, it isn't the right approach to take. Thank you for your help, this will suffice for my specific needs. My primary problem was with width, and keeping both columns as wide as possible without kicking one to the next row - but when you begin to have elements with `padding`, `margin`, and `border`, it starts to become difficult to manage those dimensions.